# Need help on a pyspark SQL query with complex requirement

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

It took me 5 mins to come up with this lame title since the problem was so complex.

### Input:

```
field1  field2  field3
A   A1  50
A   A2  70
B   B1  30
B   B2  30
B   B3  30
C   C1  45
C   C2  55
D   D1  80
D   D2  40
D   D3  50
```

### Expected Output:

```
field1  field2  field3  field4  field5
A   A1  50  50  0
A   A2  70  50  20
B   B1  30  30  0
B   B2  30  30  0
B   B3  30  30  0
C   C1  45  45  0
C   C2  55  55  0
D   D1  80  80  0
D   D2  40  20  20
D   D3  50  0   50
```

Logic:
`field1` is the key column on which the grouping needs to be done.
For every group, max of 100 can be distributed in `field4` based on `field3`.
Once it passes 100, the rest goes to `field5`.

For Ex: 
Group with field1 "A", 1st row field3 is 50. Out of 100, entire 50 goes into field4. 2nd row of the group is 70 and there is only 50 left of the initial 100. So, 50 goes into field 4 and remaining 20 goes to field5.
Is there a way to get a logic purely in pyspark-sql?

Comment: Is `field2` used for ordering?

Comment: no, it is not used for ordering (it is just a random column). the rule can be applied based on the order in which the data is in the file.

Comment: Spark DataFrames are inherently unordered. You can't just rely on the order in the file. Each record is treated as an independent block of data and thus can be processed in a distributed manner. If order is required, the user must specify how to order the data.

Comment: yes, I am aware of that. But for now if we just ignore the order and deal with it in 1st come 1st serve basis, it should be fine.